# Information Required on Gesture builder

Tags: android, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, gesture-recognition

I was using gestures in my Android application. I have done it with the help of gesture builder and used a pattern "S" for opening new activity from the current activity now I want to fix 2 issues here

**Issue 1:** when I test the application it's opening new activity for the hand written letter "S" and also it's opening new activity for "(",")","<",">" this type of text (i.e any part of the letter "S") now I want to restrict it from opening for other patterns apart from the letter "S".

**Issue 2:** when I write something on the screen with hand it's showing the pattern which I drawn, I want to hide the pattern which I drawn on the screen.

Comment: Kindly have a look and give me some idea so that I will start work on it